# Are there any secret areas in Smash Run?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, super-smash-bros-4

I was looking at the [Smash Run map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAEeW.jpg) and noticed that there are some hard to reach platforms near the corners of the map, and what looks like some hidden caves along the right side.

What hidden or secret areas are there in Smash Run? What are the benefits of getting to them?

Comment: I found one secret area while I was playing Smash Run over the weekend. I stepped onto a spot that resembled the Battlefield stage and it flew up into the sky, taking me with it. It docked between three smaller platforms, which held two chests. A bunch of enemies then appeared, and rewarded a lot of power-ups when I defeated them. The platform didn't go back down after that, so I had to jump off.

Comment: There is something in the bottom right, as well. I found a treasure chest there once.

Answer (score 2):

The bottom right corner, yes, but once every SR, one of those battlefield-like structures aboveground will shoot into the sky and send you to a secret area in the sky.

EDIT: Oh, commenter. I'm sorry that I kind of stole your thunder... :(

Answer (score 0):

Many areas in smash run for the 3ds are difficult to reach, but not impossible. Because of the fact that getting more stat boosts makes it more possible, I wouldn't consider them "secret areas," but I will briefly explain the different scenarios possible:

-The battlefield like arena has two possible endings. It can simply stop near more platforms, or you can be given a time limit to defeat enemies. Both usually reward many bonuses as when there is no battle, there is usually a chest.

-There are many areas only accessible through falling, through using the cannon barrels, or having a multi-jumper like Kirby or Jigglypuff.

-Sometimes an event will trigger a room's appearance that literally isn't on the map. These are the closest things to "secret areas."

Otherwise, anything is possible with the right fighter.